# Mutually exclusive and collectively exhaustive event

Tags: probability

List contains events $A_1$, $A_2$, $\dots$, $A_5$ which are mutually exclusive and collectively exhaustive.

Compute the following:$$\sum_{i=1}^{k}P(A_{i}^{c})$$

I didn't get what the question wants here.

Comment: Could you define what $k$ is? I assumed $k$ was just some fixed number in $\{1, 2, \dots, 5\}$.

Comment: I guess k is the list which is 5

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Suppose $k \in \{1, 2, \dots, 5\}$ is fixed. Then $\mathbb{P}\left(A_{i}^{c}\right) = 1 - \mathbb{P}\left(A_i\right)$ for all $i = 1, 2, \dots, 5$. Therefore, 
$$\sum_{i=1}^{k}\mathbb{P}\left(A_{i}^{c}\right) = k-\sum_{i=1}^{k}\mathbb{P}\left(A_{i}\right) = k - \left[1-\sum\limits_{i > k}\mathbb{P}\left(A_i\right)\right] = k - 1 + \sum\limits_{i > k}\mathbb{P}\left(A_i\right)\text{.}$$
Of course, if $k = 5$, $\sum\limits_{i > k}\mathbb{P}\left(A_i\right) = 0$.

Comment: Yes this would be the correct answer but I didn't understand $\sum\limits_{i > k}$ $$"i > k"$$

Comment: Oh, this means to sum all probabilities $\mathbb{P}\left(A_i\right)$ such that $i > k$. So of course, if $k = 5$, there aren't any events $A_i$ where $i > 5$, so then $\sum_{i > k}\mathbb{P}\left(A_i\right) = 0$.

Comment: @DenizAydemir - See the above.

Comment: Yes I saw and I understood. I have 1 more question. What would happen if we say: $$\sum_{i=1}^{k}\sum_{j=1}^{k}P(A_{i}\cap A_{j})$$

Comment: @DenizAydemir - Since $A_i$ and $A_j$ are mutually exclusive for $i \neq j$, it follows that for $i \neq j$, $\mathbb{P}\left(A_i \cap A_j\right) = 0$. But if $i = j$, what is $\mathbb{P}\left(A_i \cap A_j\right)$? I'll let you figure this one out.

Comment: @DenizAydemir - That's correct, but you don't need it for this problem. You know that $i = j$. So thus, what is $\mathbb{P}\left(A_i \cap A_j\right)$? Note that if $i = j$, $\mathbb{P}\left(A_i \cap A_j\right) = \mathbb{P}\left(A_i \cap A_i\right)$. What is the probability of the intersection of an event with itself?

Comment: Probability of the intersection of an event with itself is 1

Comment: @DenizAydemir - Exactly. So when $i = j$, you get a probability of 1. You have 5 cases for which this is true. So what does the sum $\sum\limits_{i = 1}^{k}\sum\limits_{j = 1}^{k}\mathbb{P}\left(A_i \cap A_j\right)$ evaluate to?

Comment: Which makes $5$, yes I understood our solution. But I still didn't get why the solution manuel says:
"$$\sum_{i=1}^{k}\sum_{j\neq k} P(A_{i}\cap A_{j}) + 
\sum_{i=1}^{k}P(A_i) = 0 + 1$$"

Comment: @DenizAydemir - Are you sure that's not a typo? I'm guessing $j \neq k$ is supposed to be $j \neq i$.

Comment: Yes you are right sorry for writing mistake. It's $j \neq i$

Comment: @DenizAydemir - What they have there is correct... if you sum $\mathbb{P}\left(A_i \cap A_j\right)$ over all $i$ and where $j \neq i$, you get $0$ - because $A_i$ and $A_j$ are mutually exclusive for $j \neq i$. But I'm not sure what their solution is doing, to be honest with you. I prefer mine :P

Comment: I'm writing what it says as description:
The mutually exclusive property of the Ai's will require P(Ai ∩ Aj) = 0 unless j = i. If j = i, we have P(Aj ∩ Aj), which is equal to P(Aj); so upon recalling that the Ai list is also collectively exhaustive, there follows: ....

Comment: Yeah :D I prefer yours too. Sorry for giving inconvenience, I took much time of yours. Thanks by the way.

Comment: @DenizAydemir: So what they're saying is $$\sum\limits_{i = 1}^{k}\sum\limits_{j \neq i}\mathbb{P}\left(A_i \cap A_j\right) + \sum\limits_{i = 1}^{k}\mathbb{P}\left(A_i\right) = \sum\limits_{i = 1}^{k}\sum\limits_{j \neq i}\mathbb{P}\left(A_i \cap A_j\right) + \sum\limits_{i = 1}^{k}\mathbb{P}\left(A_i \cap A_i\right) = \sum\limits_{i = 1}^{k}\sum\limits_{j = 1}^{k}\mathbb{P}\left(A_i \cap A_j\right) = 0+1 = 1\text{.}$$ Hmm. Let me think about this for a few minutes.

Comment: @DenizAydemir - Never mind... my answer of $5$ is wrong. :P $\mathbb{P}\left(A_i \cap A_i\right) = \mathbb{P}\left(A_i\right)$, not necessarily $1$.

Comment: Their solution is correct.

Answer (score 1):

Mutually Exclusive and collectively Exhaustive tells you that

$\sum_{1}^{5}P(A_i) = 1$

$P(A_i^c) = \sum_{j = 1, i\ne j}^5 P(A_j)$

$\sum_{1}^{5}P(A_i^c) = 4\times\sum_{1}^{5}P(A_i) = 4$

Thanks

Satish

Comment: if $\sum_{1}^{5}P(A_i) = 1$ then why we are multiplying by $4$ again ? I think it should be $$\sum_{1}^{5}P(A_i^c) = 5-\sum_{1}^{5}P(A_i) = 4$$